# Why would one avoid using POPF to restore Interrupt Flag state?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, interrupt, eflags

My question isn't about the fact that *BX* was used as a return value rather than placing it at a global memory location or on the stack. I observed this code being posted recently in a comment. The code was for a real-mode mouse handler using the BIOS. Two small functions that save/restore the state of the FLAGS register were as follows:

```
EFLAGS_IF        equ 0x200         ; Bit mask for IF flag in FLAGS register

; Function: save_if_flag
;           save the current state of the Interrupt Flag (IF)
;
; Inputs:   None
; Returns:  BX = 0x200 if interrupt flag is set, 0 otherwise

save_if_flag:
    pushf
    pop bx                      ; Get FLAGS into BX
    and bx, EFLAGS_IF           ; BX=0 if IF is clear, BX=0x200 if set
    ret

; Function: restore_if_flag
;           restore Interrupt Flag (IF) state
;
; Inputs:   BX = save Interrupt Flag state
; Clobbers: None
; Returns:  EFLAGS IF flag restored

restore_if_flag:
    test bx, bx                 ; Is saved Interrupt Flag zero?
    jz .if_off                  ;     If zero, then disable interrupts & finish
    sti                         ; Otherwise enable interrupts
    ret                         ; We're finished
.if_off:                        
    cli                         ; Disable interrupts
    ret
```

I'd like to understand why the `restore_if_flag` function does this:

```
restore_if_flag:
    test bx, bx                 ; Is saved Interrupt Flag zero?
    jz .if_off                  ;     If zero, then disable interrupts & finish
    sti                         ; Otherwise enable interrupts
    ret                         ; We're finished
.if_off:                        
    cli                         ; Disable interrupts
    ret
```

Rather than simply using [`POPF`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/popf:popfd:popfq) like this:

```
restore_if_flag:
    push bx
    popf
    ret
```

Why explicitly save/restore the interrupt flag using *STI/CLI* rather than simply restoring the previous FLAGS register with *POPF*?

Comment: You don't mention the context where this code is being used.  Outside of protected mode in a DOS extender I don't think it would be useful.

Comment: @RossRidge : That is sort of the point. The assumption is you don't know the context so writing the code this way would help to alleviate the issues when moved from context to context. Because `pushf` and `popf` use to get copy and pasted like cookie cutter code that ended up in code running via DOS extenders - that code ended up not working properly and many of the work around (hacks) are not always successful. As for DOS extenders, it was the reason I referenced DPMI in the answer.

Comment: @RossRidge :If one is curious, the comment this question refers to that had a link for this code was written by myself. I was queried about the code and why I did this in an email a week or to ago so thought I might explain the rationale. But yes, one reason was if someone ported the code to be run as a 32-bit protected mode DOS program using an extender - at least it would have a better chance of working. I still work with a legacy application that failed because of this problem years ago (Was written to use DOS/4GW).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you are looking at has merit. Likely the person who wrote this is aware that [`POPF`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/popf:popfd:popfq) doesn't treat the Interrupt Flag (*IF*) the same way in all the different operating modes. [image]
[image]

---

They are likely trying to avoid these two patterns of code:

```
sti
pushf                     ; Save flags including interrupts (IF)
cli
; Do work here with interrupts off
popf                      ; Restore interrupts (re-enable IF) 
; Interrupts may still be off at this point depending on mode and IO Privileges
```

or

```
cli
pushf                     ; Save flags including interrupts (IF)
sti
; Do work here with interrupts on
popf                      ; Restore interrupts to previous state 
; Interrupts may still be on at this point depending on mode and IO privileges
```

These 2 cases are where *IF* was actually changed and *POPF* is being expected to restore *IF* to its previous value. If you review the first diagram I have circled **N** . These are the cases where you are in protected mode, compatibility mode, or 64-bit mode and the Current Privilege Level (CPL) is 1,2,3 and IOPL (IO Privilege Level) < CPL. In these situation *POPF* will not generate a general protection fault and will silently ignore the change to *IF*.

Because there is no fault, the kernel doesn't have any idea that there was an attempt to change *IF* so has no chance to virtualize *IF*. *STI* and *CLI* act as privileged instructions when they don't have proper IOPL privileges and will fault to the kernel where *IF* can be virtualized by the CPU.

To the question as to why explicit *STI/CLI* is being done in the original code? An *STI/CLI* will guarantee a fault that the kernel can intercept in the cases where you don't have proper IOPL privileges to update *IF*. *POPF* may allow *IF* to become out of sync with the notion of what the program thinks the flag should be. By using *STI* and *CLI* to change *IF* you allow the kernel to more easily keep things synchronized.

---

The DPMI (DOS Protected Mode Interface) [specification](https://www.phatcode.net/res/262/files/dpmi09.html) discusses this issue and is described this way:

> 2.3 Interrupt Flag Management
>       The popf and iret instructions may not modify the state of the interrupt flag
>       since most DPMI implementations will run programs with IOPL < DPL. Programs
>       must execute cli or sti to modify the interrupt flag state.
>
> This means that the following code sequence will leave interrupts disabled:
>
> ```
>      ;
>      ; (Assume interrupts are enabled at this point)
>      ;
>      pushf
>      cli
>      .
>      .
>      popf            ; Interrupts are still OFF!
> ```
>
> Note that since some implementations of DPMI will maintain a virtual interrupt
>       state for protected mode DOS programs, the current value of the interrupt flag
>       may not reflect the current virtual interrupt state. Protected mode programs
>       should use the virtual interrupt state services to determine the current
>       interrupt flag state (see page 99).
>
> Since cli and sti are privileged instructions, they will cause a protection
>       violation and the DPMI provider will simulate the instruction. Because of the
>       overhead involved in processing the exception, cli and sti should be used as
>       little as possible. In general, you should expect either of these instructions 
>       to require at least 300 clocks.

Comment: The final comment in the "two patterns" examples look reversed, I think.  e.g. the first one should say "may still be *off*" after `cli` / `popf`, because *that* would be the surprising thing.  If interrupts were on at that point, it wouldn't be *still* because it would have just changed because of popf.

Comment: @PeterCordes : Yes, thank-you for the catch. I had slightly different code originally and didn't update the comments accordingly.